# Double y axis in a subplot

Tags: julia, julia-plots, twinx

I would like to have a double y-axis in one of my subplots; however, it seems like I am missing something about `twinx()` and `link = :x`, but I couldn't figure out what..

Plotting double y-axis using `twinx()` works fine in a standard plotting frame. However, it creates the following problem when I try to link the x-axes. What am I missing here?

```
using Plots

x = [3, 5, 7, 9];
y = [10, 20, 30 , 40];
z = [-10, -20, -30, -40];

a = plot(1:10, color = :black, legend = false)

b = plot(x, y, color = :green, legend = false)
b = scatter!(twinx(), x, z, color = :orange, legend = false)

plot(a, b, layout = (2, 1), link= :x)
```

Output:

[image]

Thank you very much!

Comment: You can try to have a look at this post that uses the pyplot backend [link](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/linking-axes/8633/2)

Comment: I have asked the same question on Julia discourse -please find the solution here: https://discourse.julialang.org/t/double-y-axes-in-a-sub-plot/82186